# How can I modify a file in VSCode?

Tags: linux, git, github, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm a beginner in Linux and Git/Github.

I tried to pull files from VSCode to github and it didn't work. It only pulled the file which I have added recently so only the one which was tracked. And the mainfile was not even modified,so it hasn't the big M behind the filename. I was watching the freecodecamp tutorial on yt about git and github for beginners and I did everything as they have shown me in the video so far.You can see it in the image below.[image: .]

**EDIT:**
@Ashutosh Yadav

```html
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git init 
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tomas/desktop/git/repo56/.git/ tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git status 
On branch master No commits yet Untracked files: (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed) README.md nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track) tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git add README.md 
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git status 
On branch master No commits yet Changes to be committed: (use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage) new file: README.md 
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git commit -m "created README" -m "Please work test!" 
[master (root-commit) b53d907] created README 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-) create mode 100644 README.md 
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git push origin master 
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. CREATED NEW REPO ON GITHUB(repo56): 
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git remote add origin git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git remote -v origin 
git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git (fetch) origin 
git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git (push) 
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git push origin master 
Enumerating objects: 3, done. Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done. Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 231 bytes | 231.00 KiB/s, done. Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 To github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git * [new branch] master -> master
```

Comment: The big ‘M’ indicates that the file has been modified locally. Now you need to ‘add’ it and ‘commit’ it, before you can ‘push’ it to GitHub. You can either do that through the command line (and learn git commands), or use the VSCODE interface. There is a tab on the left that is titled ‘Source control’ (iirc).

Comment: @RobBos I have done it through the command line and everything worked except the text which I have written "# Demo some description ## Subheader Watch out!" was not displayed in Github and I'm asking me why. I retried it several times and it does not display the written text.

Comment: In that case it seems like you forgot to push the changes to GitHub. Do make sure your upstream is connected! Run git remote -v to double check!

Comment: As I run the command that pops up:                                                                             origin  git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/demo-repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/demo-repo.git (push)

Comment: As I have commited the file through the command line that poped up:1 file changed, 0 insertions(+) but why 0 insertions when I have written sth in that file. I have also added the file before I commited....

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the given image, Your both files(README.md and index.html) are not saved.

Try these steps:

1. save both files.
2. click on this icon
   [image]
3. click on + button here.

[image]

4. Then enter your comment in message box and press on commit.

[image]

5. Then click on sync/publish button at the same place.

You are done up here. Your changes are commited and pushed on gitHub.

Comment: I have done it through the command line and everything worked except the text which I have written "# Demo some description ## Subheader Watch out!" was not displayed in Github and I'm asking me why. I retried it several times and it does not display the written text.As I have commited the file through the command line that poped up:1 file changed, 0 insertions(+) but why 0 insertions when I have written sth in that file. I have also added the file before I commited. Please help me:( It says everything is uptodate but I still can't see the written things in that file.

Comment: @Tomas edit your question and show your commands and its output. that may help us to address your problem properly.

Comment: tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git init=Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tomas/desktop/git/repo56/.git/ tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git status=
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        README.md

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git add README.md 
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git status=
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   README.md

Comment: tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git commit -m "created README" -m "Please work test!"
[master (root-commit) b53d907] created README
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README.md                              
tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: CREATED NEW REPO ON GITHUB (repo56) tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git remote add origin git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git (push) tomas@art:~/desktop/git/repo56$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 231 bytes | 231.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To github.com:TB20TB05TB/repo56.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

Comment: if that couldn't help could we please get in touch via discord or somehow because I'm starting out in programming and I'm sure I will be needing that feature in my future. I would really really appreciate that help. :)

Comment: @Tomas please edit the question. and put these info there. It provides better visibility.